# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found (sklearn)

Tags: python, numpy, dll, scikit-learn

I installed numpy, scipy and scikit-learn in Python 3.5. When I run my program, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/Cong Toan/Tools/NLP_Tools/doc_sim.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 324, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually requires `numpy`+`mkl`. But it's difficult to say if that is the problem with your distribution.

My advice is that you use one of the available distributions that already bring those libraries. I recommend [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/), but I also heard good things about [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

It's easy to install other packages with WinPython using:

[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn)

By [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/).

If you really want to solve that issue with your current distribution you'll have to provide more information such as versions that you installed, previous modules installed, and how you installed them.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem too, after days of searching and reinstalling almost every thing. I found out the answer:

Step 1: Uninstall scipy and numpy

Step 2: Dowload numpy+mkl( the package name is numpy+mkl, not numpy package and mkl package) and scipy from [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) as armatita mentioned

Step3: Install numpy+mkl first and scipy after that

Good luck to you

Comment: I had to unsinstall sklearn also. Installed numpy+mkl, scipy and then scikit_learn downloaded from the same link. 
Stopped the jupyter notebook and restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Try Anaconda, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall numpy and scipy, this fixed the problem for me.